# The Volume of the Pyramid.

Tags: geometry, 3d

i am not that much of a native speaker, so this is the best i can do with the translation:

The base of a pyramid is a rectangle measuring 9m, 12m, and each of the edges is 12.5m. find the volume of the pyramid.

this is the image as well: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3ZX.png)

I tried to solve it but turned out wrong.

[this is my shot at it, but I just know it's wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lANu.png)

the thing I'm suspecting is we have to separate the base into its diagonals, but dont know where to go from there.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Google : "volume of a pyramid with a rectangular base".  Based on this, you first have to compute the length of $(1/2)$ of the diagonal of the rectangle at the base of the pyramid.  Then, you have to solve for $h$ the height of the pyramid, using the formula $h^2 + d^2 = D^2$, where $d$ is the length of $(1/2)$ of the diagonal of the rectangle and $D$ is the (**given**) length of the $3$ dimensional diagonal that goes from a corner of the rectangle to the very top of the pyramid.

Comment: I did, but none of the results shows anything about 'how to find the height when given the edges'

Comment: I just edited my comment.

Comment: For some reason at some point you decided that the edge of the pyramyd and the slant height of the lateral face having base the smaller side of the base rectangle should both be $12.5\text{cm}$, when it should be clear that the latter is smaller.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I haven't even read yuor comment.

Comment: i think I did it! the height is 10m, and from here we can easily find the volume.

Comment: i understand it now! Thanks to you all, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since V = S*h/3, and you already have S, the hint to solve this question is to determine the value of h.

S = 9*12 = 108

h^2 = 12.5^2-(12/2)^2-(9/2)^2 = 100

h = 10 (Length is larger than 0)

V = 108*10/3 = 360